# can Fortran have an input&output command prompt in terminal?

Tags: fortran, command-prompt

Generally I use fortran to do the numerical analysis and then using matlab, R and python to do post and pre work.

What I found is that matlab, R and python provide a command prompt in terminal, so that you can run script as well as instantly execute commands from command line. However, fortran may not be working like that as I have to compile the scripts before running it. furthermore, after running the binary file compiled from script, it is not possible to inquire the data in RAM processed by running the binary, unless they are exported to files or run script in debug mode.

Just wondering if there is a way to "run" FORTRAN binary in a sort of command line, so that we can further process the data after finishing running the binary as we usually do in matlab, R, python (or even sage, mathematica?). If there isn't such kind of terminal do you have any idea about the reasons? (probably my misunderstanding on the concept of fortran, which may differ from the other languages.)

thanks in advance!

Comment: I suggest you research the topics of *compiled programming language* and *interpreted programming language* and the key differences between them, come to your own understanding of why Fortran can't be used interactively as Matlab, R and Python can.  Then, think about how you might implement an interactive computing system in Fortran. Don't be surprised if, after a few years effort, you find that you have rewritten Matlab.

Comment: Well the concept of compiled programming language and interpreted programming language is something I personally don't like. There are languages for both interpreters (or REPLs) and compilers exist. For Scheme, ML and Haskell, for example. There exist an interpreter for C and C++ (http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cint)  or for Algol and there is no principal reason why Fortran one couldn't exist (one referenced below). The standard just talks about a processor, which can be even a person with an abacus. Of course the meaning of commands entered interactively is more difficult to define.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I know of is this system at CERN. They have have also something similar for C.

http://wwwasdoc.web.cern.ch/wwwasdoc/comis/comimain.html

Answer (score 1):

You may write your calculation routines in Fortran and bind them into some interpreted language. For Python you could use the [f2py](http://www.f2py.com/) package for this.